# INSERT MASTER.sys.sysdatabases result into a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

I have this query that iterate all databases on my SQL Server

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200)
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases

where name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'SELECT ' + '''' + @DB_Name + '''' + 'as DB_name, SF.filename, SF.size FROM sys.sysfiles SF'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

But how can I store the result all in one temporary table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dan Guzman was right (in a comment he deleted) that you can just use [`master.sys.master_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql), and that you should certainly avoid old views like `sysdatabases` and `sysfiles`, but if you need to do a similar thing using data that *is not* conveniently rolled up into master for you, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @db sysname, @sql nvarchar(max), @exec nvarchar(max);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id > 4
      AND state = 0;

OPEN c;

CREATE TABLE #files(db sysname, fn nvarchar(1000), sz int); 

SET @sql = N'INSERT #files(db,fn,sz) 
    SELECT @db, physical_name, size
    FROM sys.database_files;';

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  EXEC @exec @sql, N'@db sysname', @db;
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db;
END

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;   

SELECT db, fn, sz FROM #files;

DROP TABLE #files;
```

Notice no clunky string concatenation, no messing with 16 consecutive single quotes, and what happens in your code if a database is named `oh'crap`? I keep databases like this around for exactly this reason:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'as DB_name, SF.filename, SF.size FROM sys.sysfiles SF'.

However, you could just change the script you have right now to just do this:

```
INSERT #temptable(columns) EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Command;
```

You might also be interested in the procedure I wrote, `sp_foreachdb`, as surely along the way someone will suggest you use `sp_MSForEachDB`, which is undocumented, unsupported, and horribly broken.

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

It's also part of Brent Ozar's [First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit).

Comment: My hands are clapping @Aaron Bertrand